# Expand Plot Area of Matlab Figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm making a plot and using the [legendflex](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31092-legendflex-m--a-more-flexible--customizable-legend%20%22legendflex) function off of the File Exchange and I keep running into  a problem where I have an element of the figure expanding off one side. Is there a way to expand the figure window so I can see everything being plotted?

A trivial example would be as follows:

```
bar(rand(10, 2))
legendflex({'First Series', 'Second Series'}, 'anchor', [4 8])
```

I've noticed that there's a section to the documentation in legendflex that talks about a resize function callback, but when I set that as empty and resize the figure, the legend ends up in the middle of the plot. I've tried altering the Position and OuterPosition properties but the plot always expands within the figure and the legend moves with it and continues off the edge of the figure (or doesn't move at all if I mess with the resize function).

Does anyone have a way to expand the size of a figure or "zoom out" without altering the underlying plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not exactly answering the original question, the following code does produce the desired effect:

```
bar(rand(10, 2));
ax = gca;
ax.Position = [ax.Position(1:2) ax.Position(3)*.75 ax.Position(4)];
legendflex({'First Series', 'Second Series'}, 'anchor', [4 8]);
```

This resizes the axes before adding the legend so that when it is added there's space to the right of the figure.